# What is the difference between xorg radeon and xorg radeonhd

Tags: drivers, 16.04, xorg, radeon

I install open source radeon driver from Xorg. I use a Radeon R7 board. But it doesn't work well.
So I search the package needed for my board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [radeonhd](https://www.x.org/wiki/radeonhd/):

> Status 09/2010: Linux distributions, including Novell's openSUSE, have now abandoned radeonhd as the default driver, instead using the radeon driver. radeon has more features, including Kernel Mode-Setting support and more 3D support, and it supports all Radeon generation from original R100 Radeons to R800 Radeons (HD 5000 series). Radeonhd can be continued to be updated as long as there are people find it useful.

- [radeon](https://www.x.org/wiki/radeon/):

> Driver for ATI/AMD Radeon based video chips, everything from Radeon 7000 (R100) to Radeon HD 7000 (Southern Islands) series. Part of xf86-video-ati, ie. also known as the 'ati' driver. License: MIT
>
> But it doesn't work well. So I search the package needed for my board.

If the open source version does not do well with your system:

1. File a bug report against package "radeon".
2. Re-install 14.04 and stick to it for now since [AMD did not release 3rd party drivers for Ubuntu 16.04](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/ubuntu-drops-amd-catalyst-fglrx-driver-16-04). So you have no options but the open source version.

Comment: ok thank you for your response. And xserver-xorg-video-ati vs xserver-xorg-video-radeon ?

Comment: xserver-xorg-video-ati is a driver wrapper and  xserver-xorg-video-ati is a hardware-specific driver package. The ati wrapper driver autodetects whether your hardware has a Radeon, Rage 128, or Mach64 or earlier chip and load the radeon, r128, or mach64 xorg video driver as appropriate.